StepReg library won't load in R
I'm trying to construct a prognostic prediction model. To do this I've installed the StepReg package. However, whenever I try to load StepReg from my library, it comes up with a bunch of error messages.
> library(StepReg)
The operation couldn’t be completed. Unable to locate a Java Runtime.
Please visit http://www.java.com for information on installing Java.

Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘StepReg’:
 .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
  call: fun(libname, pkgname)
  error: JVM could not be found
In addition: Warning messages:
1: package ‘StepReg’ was built under R version 4.3.2 
2: In system("/usr/libexec/java_home", intern = TRUE) :
  running command '/usr/libexec/java_home' had status 1
3: In fun(libname, pkgname) :
  Cannot find JVM library 'NA/lib/server/libjvm.dylib'
Install Java and/or check JAVA_HOME (if in doubt, do NOT set it, it will be detected)

It mentions Java so I tried installing a JavaGD package but it still does the same thing.

You need a Java Virtual Machine. See here [link] (https://www.java.com/en/download/help/linux_x64_install.html). You may also need the rJava R package installed.

Hi @Lauren, I agree with DavoOZ and you may try to install my latest version from Github using the following code devtools::install_github("JunhuiLi1017/StepReg", ref="dev", force = TRUE).
